# Comando avatar para bot no discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

estou com problema no comando, consigo dar avatar de boa porém ele "ignora" os usuários que usam gif e transforma ele em jpg

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //puxo a api aqui pq deu um embed
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar', //o nome pra puxar o comando
  aliases: ['foto', 'icon', 'pfp'],//nomes alternativos
  //Descrição dele
    description: 'Pegue a URL de avatar do user mencionado.', 
  //conando abaixo, após o execute()
  cooldown: 5,//tempo de espera pra executar novamente
      async execute (msg, args) {

if (!msg.mentions.users.size) {
   return msg.channel.send('Ninguém mencionado');
    //tirei pra ver o proprio avatar
    //caso queira colocar 
    //msg.channel.send(`seu avatar: ${msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
}

const avatarList = msg.mentions.users.map(user => {
          let nicer = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //Criei o embed antes do return
        .setTitle(`${user.username}'s avatar`) 
        .setImage(`${user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024 })}`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
         
         return msg.channel.send(nicer); //Retornei o embed
;

        });
        
        
        
}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

  let user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author;
  
  let avatar = user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 });

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor(`#00000`) 
    .setTitle(`Avatar de ${user.username}`) 
    .setImage(avatar) 
    .setFooter(`• Autor: ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"}));
 await message.channel.send(embed); 

};
```

Se quiser mudar a cor da barra, aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> pra achar `setColor('#00000')` e troque os números.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  let user =
    message.mentions.users.first() ||
    client.users.cache.get(args[0]) ||
    message.author;

  let avatar = user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 });

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(`#4cd8b2`)
    .setTitle(`Avatar de ${user.username}`)
    .setImage(avatar)
    .addField(
      `**Avatar de: ${user.username}**`,
      `Clique **[aqui](${avatar})** para baixar o avatar.`
    )
    .setFooter(
      `• Autor: ${message.author.tag}`,
      message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png" })
    );
  await message.channel.send(embed);
};
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).